# Python script fails to extract data from XML

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml

**I'm trying to parse and fetch data through this XML file. But my code isn't working as intended, rather it displays nothing. This is the XML file I'm using:**

```
<feed xml:base="http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/">
  <title type="text">DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData</title>
  <id>
    http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData
  </id>
  <updated>2019-11-04T07:15:32Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData"/>
  <entry>
    <id>
      http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7258)
    </id>
    <title type="text"/>
    <updated>2019-11-04T07:15:32Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name/>
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7258)"/>
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7258</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2019-01-02T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.4</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_2MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.4</d:BC_2MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.42</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.51</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.6</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.5</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.47</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.49</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.56</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.66</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.83</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.97</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.97</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
  <id>
    http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7259)
  </id>
  <title type="text"/>
  <updated>2019-11-04T07:15:32Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name/>
  </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7259)"/>
  <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7259</d:Id>
      <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2019-01-03T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
      <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.42</d:BC_1MONTH>
      <d:BC_2MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.42</d:BC_2MONTH>
      <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.41</d:BC_3MONTH>
      <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.47</d:BC_6MONTH>
      <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.5</d:BC_1YEAR>
      <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.39</d:BC_2YEAR>
      <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.35</d:BC_3YEAR>
      <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.37</d:BC_5YEAR>
      <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.44</d:BC_7YEAR>
      <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.56</d:BC_10YEAR>
      <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.75</d:BC_20YEAR>
      <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.92</d:BC_30YEAR>
      <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.92</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
<entry>
  <id>
    http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7260)
  </id>
  <title type="text"/>
  <updated>2019-11-04T07:15:32Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name/>
  </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7260)"/>
  <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
  <content type="application/xml">
     <m:properties>
       <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7260</d:Id>
       <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2019-01-04T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
       <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.4</d:BC_1MONTH>
       <d:BC_2MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.42</d:BC_2MONTH>
       <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.42</d:BC_3MONTH>
       <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.51</d:BC_6MONTH>
       <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.57</d:BC_1YEAR>
       <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.5</d:BC_2YEAR>
       <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.47</d:BC_3YEAR>
       <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.49</d:BC_5YEAR>
       <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.56</d:BC_7YEAR>
       <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.67</d:BC_10YEAR>
       <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.83</d:BC_20YEAR>
       <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.98</d:BC_30YEAR>
       <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.98</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
     </m:properties>
   </content>
 </entry>
</feed>
```

**So far I've tried this:**

```
import requests as rq
import lxml.etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData')
root = tree.getroot()

for ele in root.xpath('./entry/content/m:properties', 
                  namespaces={'m': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme'}):
    print(ele)
    for foo in ele:
        print(foo.tag, foo.text)
```

**But, nothing is displayed.**

I expect the output to be:

```
NEW_DATE 2019-10-31T00:00:00
BC_1MONTH 1.59
BC_2MONTH 1.59
BC_3MONTH 1.59
BC_6MONTH 1.57
BC_1YEAR 1.54
BC_2YEAR 1.52
BC_3YEAR 1.52
BC_5YEAR 1.51
BC_7YEAR 1.6
BC_10YEAR 1.69
BC_20YEAR 2
BC_30YEAR 2.17
BC_30YEARDISPLAY 2.17
```

Similarly, it should loop onto complete XML and generate similar output! Please tell me where am I wrong.

Comment: Your XML file is missing a closing `</feed>` tag.

Comment: Properly intending the file usually avoids errors like these, btw.

Comment: There are no declarations for the `m` and `d` namespace prefixes in the XML document.

Comment: @mario_sunny Yeah, it was indentation mistake on stack overflow, I have corrected it, but it isn't working!

Comment: There is no namespace definition for `m:` in your sample XML. There should be a `xmlns:m="..."` somewhere in the original data.

Comment: ...the same goes for `d:`, as mzjn has already noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily using `python-benedict`, an amazing `dict` subclass.

To install it just run `pip install python-benedict`, then:

```py
data_xml = """
<feed xml:base="http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/">
  <title type="text">DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData</title>
  <id>
    http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData
  </id>
  <updated>2019-11-04T07:15:32Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData"/>
  <entry>
    <id>
      http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7258)
    </id>
    <title type="text"/>
    <updated>2019-11-04T07:15:32Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name/>
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7258)"/>
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7258</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2019-01-02T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.4</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_2MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.4</d:BC_2MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.42</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.51</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.6</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.5</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.47</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.49</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.56</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.66</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.83</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.97</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.97</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
  <id>
    http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7259)
  </id>
  <title type="text"/>
  <updated>2019-11-04T07:15:32Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name/>
  </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7259)"/>
  <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7259</d:Id>
      <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2019-01-03T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
      <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.42</d:BC_1MONTH>
      <d:BC_2MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.42</d:BC_2MONTH>
      <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.41</d:BC_3MONTH>
      <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.47</d:BC_6MONTH>
      <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.5</d:BC_1YEAR>
      <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.39</d:BC_2YEAR>
      <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.35</d:BC_3YEAR>
      <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.37</d:BC_5YEAR>
      <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.44</d:BC_7YEAR>
      <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.56</d:BC_10YEAR>
      <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.75</d:BC_20YEAR>
      <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.92</d:BC_30YEAR>
      <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.92</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
<entry>
  <id>
    http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7260)
  </id>
  <title type="text"/>
  <updated>2019-11-04T07:15:32Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name/>
  </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7260)"/>
  <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
  <content type="application/xml">
     <m:properties>
       <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7260</d:Id>
       <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2019-01-04T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
       <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.4</d:BC_1MONTH>
       <d:BC_2MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.42</d:BC_2MONTH>
       <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.42</d:BC_3MONTH>
       <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.51</d:BC_6MONTH>
       <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.57</d:BC_1YEAR>
       <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.5</d:BC_2YEAR>
       <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.47</d:BC_3YEAR>
       <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.49</d:BC_5YEAR>
       <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.56</d:BC_7YEAR>
       <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.67</d:BC_10YEAR>
       <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.83</d:BC_20YEAR>
       <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.98</d:BC_30YEAR>
       <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.98</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
     </m:properties>
   </content>
 </entry>
</feed>
"""
```

Now inizialize a `benedict` instance:

```
from benedict import benedict as bdict

# this method accepts a data string, a file path or a file url
data = bdict.from_xml(data_xml)
# print(data.dump())

entries = data['feed.entry']
for entry in entries:
    props = bdict(bdict(entry)['content.m:properties'])
    # print(props.dump())
    
    for key, value in props.items():
        print(key, value['#text'])
    print('-----')
```

`python-benedict` is well tested, documented and **open-source** on GitHub:

https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict

Disclaimer: I am the author of this project.

Comment: Surprising your module reads in a non well-formed XML (see comments regarding namespaces). It must not be DOM compliant to W3C standards. Cursory view of Git repo shows built-in `etree` or third-party `lxml` is not used.

Comment: python-benedict uses xmltodict: https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict/search?q=xmltodict

Comment: Yes, `python-benedict` uses `xmltodict` under the hood to convert from/to xml and it's possible to pass some decoder-specific options using kwargs: https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict#from_xml

Comment: Yes, if `bdict.from_xml(data_xml, process_namespaces=True)` is used, then there is  an error: "xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: unbound prefix".

Comment: @FabioCaccamo Wow! That worked like charm. Thanks a lot!